# How to get report data base on employee Name split in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these three tables:

Table_Project:

```
   ProjectId   ProjectName
  -------------------------
        1             A
        2             B
        3             C
```

Table_Employee:

```
EmployeeId       Name  
--------------------------
    1            Jhon
    2            Jason
```

Table_Task:

```
        Id    ProjectId   EmployeeId    TaskName    TaskMinute    StartDate         EndDate
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1       1            1           xyz1           10         2024/03/17       2024/03/17
        2       2            1           xyz2           30         2024/03/17       2024/03/17
        3       1            1           xyz3           40         2024/03/17       2024/03/17
        4       2            2           kkk            90         2024/03/17       2024/03/17
        5       3            2           kk1            10         2024/03/17       2024/03/17
```

I need an output as shown here and split employee wise data with footer total sum task minutes and this data of current month match with EndDate

```
Jhon      ProjectName   TaskName   TaskMinute   
            A           xyz1         10
            B           xyz2         30
            A           xyz3         40
                        Toal         80
Jason       B           kkk          90
            c           kk1          10
                       Total         100
```

Is there way to achieve like above output or any different way that contains like above data?

I have tried by inner join but not getting logic

```
 select P.ProjectName,e.Name,t.TaskMinute from Table_Task t 
 inner join Table_Project p on t.projectid=p.ProjectIdId
 inner join Table_Employee e on t.employeeid=e.EmployeeId
 group by ProjectName,
 e.Name
 t.TaskMinute
```

Comment: Hi can you update question and share what you tried to get this done ? And share why that failed?

Comment: what you need update in the question i have trying by using join but not getting to me. @Luuk

Comment: Check i have updated question. @Luuk

Comment: You need to apply the Rollup option with GROUP BY clause. https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-rollup/

Comment: can you update answer will help full to me. @SQL006

Comment: How each employee total will happened?.@SQL006

Comment: For those who want to help, here is a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/xHkW6eRu)    (small change to column names done, because of .... ?)

Comment: @mrcoder: Stackoverflow is **not** a free code writing website. You have to do _some_ things yourself.......

Comment: I am new to sql writing query thats why posted here also i am not getting logic, tell me the concept to achieve will try or sample code. @luuk

Comment: Also talented is god gifted item from each person have different thinking so not getting logic thats why posted here. @Luuk

Comment: Why you have created Fiddle?@Luuk

Comment: @mrcoder: The fiddle is create to show you (and others) that you want/need a column `TaskName`, and cannot/didnot produce one in the query your provided.  Hiding behind some _gods gift_ is not the way to go... (IMHO)

Comment: group by grouping set this is first time  looking in my career thats why stack flow help us. @Luuk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i think this should be handled in your frontend side of things, you can sort of fake the footers by using GROUPING SETS.
Using Luuk's fiddle as base:

```sql
select case when projectName is not NULL THEN Name END AS Name, ProjectName, ISNULL(TaskName, 'Total') AS TaskName, Time
from (
select e.Name,P.ProjectName,TaskName,SUM(CAST(t.TaskMinute AS BIGINT)) AS Time
from Task t 
inner join Project p on t.projectid=p.ProjectId
inner join Employee e on t.employeeid=e.EmployeeId
group by grouping sets(Name,(Name,projectName,TaskName, TaskMinute))
  ) x
ORDER BY x.Name, CASE WHEN x.ProjectName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, x.ProjectName, x.TaskName
```

Outputs:

| Name | ProjectName | TaskName | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jason | B | kkk | 90 |
| Jason | C | kk1 | 10 |
| NULL | NULL | Total | 100 |
| Jhon | A | xyz1 | 10 |
| Jhon | A | xyz3 | 40 |
| Jhon | B | xyz2 | 30 |
| NULL | NULL | Total | 80 |

Grouping sets allows generating some extra groupings which is very handy for this task

Comment: You are my hero sir will check update answer. @siggemannen